# C# WP8 Connect to MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am struggling to figure out how to connect to a MySql database in my C# Windows Phone 8 application like I can on my desktop application. The reason I am struggling is because it seems I cannot just use the same MySql.Data library that I used on my desktop application. Are there any other libraries that I can use to access my database?

PS. I really don't want to go the PHP route because I will have to have Apache running on y server two and will have to add JSON interfacing two which will not only be a hassle but possibly also waste some processing time and make my application more complex.

PPS. If not possible with MySql, can it be made to work with Microsoft SQL Server or Azure?

EDIT:
If some sort of HTTP interface is my only option, is there some easy existing API or something that I can use to allow SQL data transmission or will I have to create specific PHP(/asp.net or whatever) code for each type request that I am planning to send?

Comment: There aren't many database drivers natively available for Windows Phone (or for other phone platforms). The nature of the (dis)connections, security, etc. aren't a good match often for a phone application. It's often best if you introduce a middle-tier of some sort (It could certainly be ASP.NET and C# rather than PHP).

Comment: @WiredPrairie with PHP I was actually just referring to using a middle-tier but it seems I have no other option, is there any simple existing api or something that will allow me to communicate SQL requests with the server or will I have to make a specific implementation for each type of request I plan on sending?

Comment: If you're a C#/ASP.NET developer, you might look at: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @Gerhman I have at least 5 apps that communicate both ways with a mysql database with php as the facilitator. If you are interested I will give you the boiler plate code I use for almost every app. Its about 4 lines at most.

Comment: @AMR I would appreciate it if you could provide me with the code, I am just struggling to get PHP running on my linux box but the code should be helpful none the less (maybe I'll have to translate to aps.net...)

Comment: No problem. Im at work so give me a little time to post it. I will post it as an answer today. It really isn't that hard youll see. When you use php for your middle man in the communication process you have a ton of command and control over your data. PHP is nice because you don't have to worry about people seeing your code. It will always execute on the server and return html. I use it for everything.